# better way to invoke a method or function in php

Tags: php, function, oop, methods

I just wanted to know which one is the better approach of invoking a method / function:

```
$objS = $this->loadMyVars( PATH_FILES_TO_LOAD, $boolLoadParentData = true, $boolLoadSomeExtraInfo = true );
```

or

```
//Comment Describing about invoking method and passed values
$objS = $this->loadMyVars( PATH_FILES_TO_LOAD, true, true );
```

I find that

**First Approach:-** is self explanatory but creating two extra local vars which will be required to create and destroy unnecessary.

**Second Approach:-** is not creating any overhead but need to write proper comment to explain the invocation of `loadMyVars` method.

Please suggest me which approach I should follow.

Comment: This is among one of the reasons why IDE's were developed, makes no difference when you documentate the methods parameters accordingly ..

Comment: @dbf yes IDEs are there but still if we have to choose from either of the approach which one should be used?

Comment: It's irrelevant, the definition of the method has its parameters defined, therefore when anybody wants to use a method, they have to lookup the parametric. If I take your first approach, it won't tell me anything, the documentation behind the method that was defined will tell me what the first or second parameter is, of what type it may be and what to expect from its behavior, not your variable naming convention. If you do not handle your documentation accordingly, your first and second approaches are either way useless without inspecting the code ..